# Spring Shared bean concept - per App Server

Tags: java, spring, enterprise, portal

I have a portal server. There are number of portlets installed. I have environment configs file which is same for all portlets installed on that app server. I am using apache commons-configuration for managing from the configuration files.

Right now, each portlet/component build their own EnvConfiguration bean from these files. Obviously this is eating up more memory. I want to separate out the creation of EnvConfiguration bean and share it across all the portlets. Basically, I want to create only one bean per app server.

What are the best possible ways to do this? And how will this common beans(s) injected into the needed components?

Edit: This is a liferay application and non EAR model

Thanks 
Sundar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parentContextKey web.xml param.
Here is a blog post explaining how : http://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

The idea is to package and declare the beans you want to share in a common jar (if you use Tomcat, you can put it in the server lib folder). The beans are declared in a file called beanRefContext.xml (default name, can be changed), with an id. Then you add the param "parentContextKey" in the web.xml of your webapps with the id previously mentionned.

Comment: In fact, I only used it on a non-ear model (Tomcat with multiple wars), so yes.